# why do we analyse the housing market from 'short run' and 'long run'?

Tags: macroeconomics

As we can see the factors impacting the housing market, particularly house prices, are always analysed from the long run and short run, even some researchers analyse those factors from a cyclical and structural approach. How can we understand the long run and short run? And what are cyclical and structural influences on house price?

Comment: This seems more suited for economics se: http://economics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In the long run, we are all dead.

Comment: I vote to close because this belongs on http://economics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's very complicated. No knows the true oracle function. We just see patterns and guess functions and hope that our guesses are close enough to the unknown oracle. We test our guesses by previous data that we had the chance to also observe their output, and based on that we guess again that since our function have reasonably guessed past data correctly it hopefully might also guess future data correctly.

You may use short-term data, long-term data, mid-term data, or do time series analysis by which time is more granular.

I *think* long-term data gives you the general stable seasonal patterns (like seasonal patterns), and short-term data give you the more granular patterns (like daily or monthly weather prediction). But I am not sure about any of this.